# Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral in a circle with diameter $AC$, and let $DE \perp AB$ with $E$ on $AB$. If $AD = DC$, $[ABCD] = 24$ cm$^2$.

Tags: geometry, circles, problem-solving, polygons

> Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral in a circle with diameter $AC$, and let $DE \perp AB$ with $E$ on $AB$. If $AD = DC$, $[ABCD] = 24$ cm$^2$. Find $(DE)^2$.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

This problem has been eating my brain for quite some time now, and I tried it in many ways but in the end I succeeded doing it. The picture shows it.

First, we have that $BC$ $||$ $ED$ , which is obvious from the information. Next is that since $AD = DC$ , $BD$ is the angle bisector of $\angle BAC$ which gives $BED$ an isosceles triangle and $DE = BE$. Now draw a perpendicular from $C$ to $DE$ and let it intersect at $F$ . We have that $\Delta AED \cong \Delta DFC$ from $RHS$ , and this gives all the necessary piece of info in the picture, also noting that $CFEB$ is a rectangle. This total areas of the $2$ triangles and the rectangle gives the area of the quadrilateral, which looks really good.

From here :-
$$[ABCD] = 2[\Delta AED] + [CFEB]$$
$$\rightarrow 24 = x(x + y) + y(x + y)$$
$$\rightarrow 24 = (x + y)^2$$
$$\rightarrow (x + y) = DE = \sqrt{24}$$

Hence $DE^2 = 24$ .

This solution was so elegant that I couldn't resist posting it in Stack Exchange, maybe others will be helpful with this.

As a note, I will be waiting for some other solutions too :) .

Comment: Just like in one of previous question, rotate $AED$ counterclockwise $90^{\circ}$ about D to complete a square of side $DE = EB$. Both will have equal area.

Comment: Yes, but isn't it hard to come up with the idea??

Comment: Once you have seen and absorbed it, it shouldn't be. You can also see some other rotation problems on this site. If you want to avoid rotation, complete the square and show missing triangle in there is congruent to ADE. Remember that any triangle is half a parallelogram and any right triangle half a rectangle.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution.

First, we note that $ABC$ and $ADC$ are right triangles, and angles $A$ and $C$ in triangle $ADC$ are $45^{\circ}$.

We may also note that $\widehat{DBA}$ faces the same arc as $\widehat{DCA}$ , therefore it should be $45^{\circ}$ too. As a result, in the right triangle $DEB$ we have $DE = EB$  (This interesting information is not part of my solution but I just added it for aesthetic reasons).

Let's add $YXA$ , a rotated copy of the triangle $ABC$ to the shape, as shown in the figure below.

[image]
$XA$ is on the same line as $BA$ . We have:
$$\widehat{BCA}=\widehat{XAY}$$
$$\widehat{BCA} + \widehat{BAC} = 90^{\circ}$$
It follows that
$$\widehat{XAY} + \widehat{BAC} = 90^{\circ}$$
$$\widehat{CAY} = 180 - (\widehat{XAY} + \widehat{BAC}) = 90^{\circ}$$
$$\widehat{DAY} = \widehat{CAY} - \widehat{DAC} = 45^{\circ}$$
The triangles $ADC$ and $ADY$ have an equal angle ($\widehat{DAC} = \widehat{DAY} = 45^{\circ}$) with equal sides ($AC=AY$ and they share $AD$) , therefore they are equal and:
$$DY=DC$$
$$\widehat{ADY} = \widehat{ADC} = 90^{\circ}$$
This means that $Y$ , $D$ and $C$ are on the same line. Moreover, this line is divided into equal segments by the three parallel lines $CB$ , $DE$ and $YX$ . In other words, in the trapezoid $CBXY$ , line segment $DE$ , which is parallel to the bases, bisects the legs $CY$ and $BX$ . It follows that
$$DE = \frac{1}{2}(CB + YX)$$
And recalling that $YX = AB$ , we have:
$$DE = \frac{1}{2}(CB + AB)$$

Now we can move on to the calculation of area.
$$S_{ABCD} = S_{ABC} + S_{ADC}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}(AB.CB + AD^2)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}(AB.CB + \frac{1}{2}AC^2)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}(AB.CB + \frac{1}{2}(AB^2 + CB^2))$$
$$= \frac{1}{4}(AB + CB)^2$$
$$= DE^2$$
Voila: $S_{ABCD} = DE^2$ ! (This is an exclamation mark, not a factorial)